# Standart hotkeys palette has been changed. How to set default?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I have some problem that I never had before, my hotkeys palette has been changed. Now when I press SUPER it spreads all windows but actually in one window, but I always used SUPER + W to spread all windows.
Who knows how to fix it?

P.S. In my Guest account everything is fine.

It should be like this:
[image]

And I have this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. That's was my fault. I changed "Switch to previous source using" in Text Entry setting that's become a reason that my Keyboards shortcuts have been changed to unknown combinations for me